# How to prevent the multiple click on div in polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have created a web application with Polymer where I implemented album functionality, when I click on the album multiple times the album products are repeated multiple times.
How can I fix this issue?

```html
<div class='catelogGrid' on-tap="_openAlbumDetailsDialog" productobj ="[[productAlbum.productKey]]" value="[[productAlbum]]">
<ul style='margin:0;'>
  <template is='dom-repeat' items='[[productAlbum.albumProdImages]]' as='productImage'>
    <li>
      <img src='[[productImage.imageURL]]'>
    </li>
  </template>
  <li>
    <div name="album" title='View Album Product'>
      <span> + {{productAlbum.albumProdLength}}</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Help me to fix this.

Comment: Show us what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: No sir actually i am new in polymer but in the AngualrJS i will fix this issue?

Comment: is not clear the issue, can you create a fiddle where we can replicate the  problem?

Comment: At least TRY to solve it first before coming to stackoverflow asking for help! write some code on your own!

Comment: ok sir i will try